# Highcharts and multiple categories on x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to pass to highcharts X axis more than one array of data

Something like this:

- X axis: categories_ms (time), string categories, some other string category.
- Y axis: some values

I want a simple thing: 'Show me the tooltip with a string name of category related to time on X axis'

When I stand mouse on point I want to see a common tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        r = 'name of additional category value related to time value'
        return r;
}
```

But I don't know how to pass string categories with numerical categories.
I though that it will be possible with string list instead of int list in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-multi-axes/. But not.

What is a correct solution for such tasks?

Comment: Could you provide the full javascript code of your Highcharts chart please ?

Comment: Could you elaborate why you cannot set all text in each category ? Or full text of category should be visible only in the tooltip?

Comment: x axis = category with time values (it is visible on X axis)

I would show additional information (additional categories) in tooltip, right!

Comment: Simply, keep your categories in external arrays and use them inside `tooltip.formatter` by using adequate index. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sLn9mqj0/.